# Switching img src at certain viewport

Tags: jquery

Completely stumped as to why this is not working. Trying to switch an image source when the viewport is less than 500px, probably something really silly I am doing wrong but just can't see it.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {


var width = $(window).width();

if (width <= 500) {

$("#my-image").attr("src","images/img-2.png");
} else {
$("#my-image").attr("src","images/img-1.png");
}

});

<div>

  <img id="my-image">

</div>
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/resize/

Comment: Do you expect the image to change when the width is changed, or just depending on initial width?

Comment: ah, hadn't thought about that was just looking at the initial view but when the width is changed would be much better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a full example of using `resize()`

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var img = $("#my-image");

    var $window = $(window).on('resize', function(){
        var width = $window.width();

        if (width <= 500) {
            img.attr("src","images/img-2.png");
        } else {
            img.attr("src","images/img-1.png");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: That worked for me but initially the src is blank.  So I added your original code right after "$(document).ready(function () {"

Comment: Thanks @user1636946 was just trying to work that out as I am having the same problem. Could you post the full code?

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
$( window ).resize(function() {

});
```

Then check the width each time the window is resized.

Comment: would this just replace the width variable? I am by no means a JS expert : (